# Expending and Collapsing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 1 session of collapse and expend with JavaScript.  It works very well.

HTML

```
<h4 id="expanderHead" style="cursor:pointer;">
    EXPANDING COLLAPSING DIV <span id="expanderSign">+</span>
</h4>
<div id="expanderContent" style="display:none">
    content<br />
    content<br />
    content<br />
    content<br />
    content<br />
</div>
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#expanderHead").click(function(){
        $("#expanderContent").slideToggle();
        if ($("#expanderSign").text() == "+"){
            $("#expanderSign").html("−")
        }
        else {
            $("#expanderSign").text("+")
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

And then I add one or more sessions of collapse and expend, they don't work.  I change ID to CLASS, I click on one, it expends all (because it is the same class name).  If I keep the same ID, only the first one works.  Any way to get it work?

HTML

```
<h4 class="expanderHead" style="cursor:pointer;">
    EXPANDING COLLAPSING DIV <span id="expanderSign">+</span>
</h4>
<div class="expanderContent" style="display:none">
    content<br />
    content<br />
    content<br />
    content<br />
    content<br />
</div>



<h4 class="expanderHead" style="cursor:pointer;">
        EXPANDING COLLAPSING DIV <span id="expanderSign">+</span>
    </h4>
    <div class="expanderContent" style="display:none">
        content<br />
        content<br />
        content<br />
        content<br />
        content<br />
    </div>
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".expanderHead").click(function(){
        $(".expanderContent").slideToggle();
        if ($("#expanderSign").text() == "+"){
            $("#expanderSign").html("−")
        }
        else {
            $("#expanderSign").text("+")
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `id` is unique, you need to change `id="expanderSign"` to `class="expanderSign"`.

Then you can do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".expanderHead").click(function(){
        $(this).next().slideToggle();
        if ( $(this).find('.expanderSign').text() == "+"){
            $(this).find('.expanderSign').text("−");
        }
        else {
            $(this).find('.expanderSign').text("+");
        }
    });
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MY7ab/1/)**

or you can shorten your code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".expanderHead").click(function(){
        $(this).next().slideToggle();
        $(this).find('.expanderSign').text(function(_, v) {
            return v == "+" ? "-" : "+";
        })
    });
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MY7ab/2/)**

Comment: Thank you very much, Felix! I didn't thought of `$(this).find('.expanderSign').text() == "+"){$(this).find('.expanderSign').text("−");'  It works now.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".expanderHead").click(function(){
        $(this).next(".expanderContent").slideToggle();
        if ($(this).children("span").text() == "+"){
            $(this).children("span").html("−")
        }
        else {
            $(this).children("span").text("+")
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Please note your both span has same id "expanderSign" , which should not be the case ! Hence I have used SPAN as selector.